# Fetching a json outside of react root

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I've got a project which has an "old" javascript/php app. It contains dozen of json files for getting data from the database.

Besides that I'm going to migrate some modules to react but still want to use those json files for now. Is it possible to fetch the json files from the react app? Both apps are in the same repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets pretend you have this folder structure:

```
/
/LegacyApp
/LegacyApp/file.json
/NewApp/index.js
```

Then you can simply import the files from your new app via the `require` function:

```js
// inside index.js

const data = require('../LegacyApp/file.json')

// Or newer ES6 Syntax
import data from '../LegacyApp/file.json'
```

That JSON-file will be imported as a JavaScript object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer? What if I want to fetch it because I need to set some parameters for getting the right data?

Comment: `const data = require('../LegacyApp/' + fileName);`